# How would I integrate values with a discrete time step and discrete distance that correspond to a specific velocity value?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, data-analysis

I am just curious to how I would go about integrating data points that I get from a simulation that I am running ? In this simulation I get velocity values along a line (i.e alonge the line $x=3$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$) at discrete distance markers (say 0.5 step size) but the values for these are taken at a specific time step during the simulation. I am wondering how would I be able to integrate this line so I can get values for the velocity as a function of distance and time and then to plot it ?

Here would be an example of the data points I would be given (u,v,h are the variable for the velocities just for clarity):

$$ at \ \ t=0 :
 \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\Delta y& u & v & h \\ \hline
 0& 0& 0& 0\\ \hline
 0.5 & 1.0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\ \hline
 1& 2.0 & 1.0& 1.0\\ \hline
\end{array} 
\\
at \ \ t=0.5:
 \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\Delta y& u & v & h \\ \hline
 0& 0& 0& 0\\ \hline
 0.5 & 0.75 & 1.5 & 0.5\\ \hline
 1& 2.0 & 1.0& 1.0\\ \hline
\end{array} $$

These are not the exact values that I get from my simulation but rather an example of how my data is stored.

My first intuition is to integrate along the $\Delta y$ line at each time step and then to go back and integrate those lines for all time, i.e integrate along the line for $t=0$ and $t=0.5$ then integrate those lines for all time.

But the problem with my intuition that I am second guessing is

1. Wouldn't that take an extremely long time for small enough $\Delta y$ and large enough $t$ ?
2. What kind of integration methods would be used to do this ?
3. Wouldn't that take up a lot of memory doing each integration independently ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and any suggestions on either changing up my idea of thinking/suggesting a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

**Note** I can post a couple of actual data files on Github and share them if my example wasn't clear enough or you want to see exactly how the data is laid out in .txt files.

Comment: You indicate you have nine velocity variables at time $t=0.$ Velocities of _what?_ And how would integration come into this--what should the integral tell you about? What problem really are you trying to solve?

Comment: Could you explain the function a little more, is it like a vector function like $$f(t)=\langle u(x(t),y(t)), v(x(t),y(t)), h(x(t),y(t))\rangle $$

Comment: And integrate is $$\int_a^b f(t)dt=\int_a^b u(t)dt + \int_a^b v(t)dt+\int_a^b h(t)dt$$ a vector? . Not clear why there are three values for a single $t$.

Comment: Or is $y=t$ and $x=3$?

Comment: Ok so $f(x,y,t) \to (u,v,h) \ \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, $x$ and $t$ are fixed and $y$ varies from $ 0 \le y \le 1 $ for a time step?

Comment: @marshalcraft I apologize if I wasn't clear enough and I will try to clear that up here. So the velocities u,v,h are the velocities in the x,y,z direction respectfully, i.e $\vec{U} = \langle u(x),v(y),h(z) \rangle $. The problem is from a fluid dynamics perspective, in that I am trying to calculate the drag force on an object. What I would ideally like to have is to be able to bring it from a discrete values to a single function for which I could specify the time and location and get the corresponding velocity and integration was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: @marshalcraft So the way it is set up is that the data is collected along the line x=3 but at discrete step sizes increasing in the y (which is bounded between 0 and 1) it records a velocity value, So at $\Delta t_n = 0.1*n$ (the discrete time step) for every position $\Delta y_{n}$ is the step size of $0.1*n$ then at $(\Delta y_0 ,x=3)$ we will have a value of $\vec{U}$ and $(\Delta y_1 ,x=3)$ we will have a second value of $\vec{U}$ and this is done until $\Delta y_{n} = 1$ and then it does the same process for $\Delta t_{n+1} $

Comment: It makes a big difference to know that these are velocities of fluids. It's a little unclear still why you are only interested in $0<y<1$ and $x=3,$ but if all you really need is to get the velocity $(u(x,y,t),v(x,y,t),h(x,y,t))$ as a continuous function along the segment from $(3,0)$ to $(3,1),$ I think _interpolation_ (not integration!) is what you may be looking for.

Comment: I like $\mathbf U(x, y, t)= \langle u(x,y,t), v(x,y,t), h(x,y,t) \rangle$ your data and question doesn't make use of a $z$, but you could include it then $\Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^3$. But without the $z$ it would be fluid in the $z$ plane or there is no interaction in the $z$ direction.

Comment: You are varying $y,t$ and getting a vector result. $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$. Can you explain the integral of the vector valued function, there are several possibilities, ie path integral, etc.

Comment: @DavidK My attempt is to try and get the mass flux to then get the force (Kind of validating what is in my textbook) and I do believe that is what I am looking for, my mistake. But for the interpolation would what I initially thought of doing, interpolating along the segment $(3,0)$ to $(3,1)$ and then interpolating it again for the time be the best approach, say spline interpolation ? or is there a better method ? and obviously if it would be better I can make another thread with the updated insight into my mistaken initial choice.

Comment: @marshalcraft I do believe my initial thought was wrong in that I wouldn't need to do the integration but rather interpolation of my data set.

Comment: If you simply want a continuous model or approximation that is one thing and you can use interpolation, or some order series approximation. Another aspect is if you want an approximation for more accurate integration, like using quadratic cuves to connect finite points instead of lines.

Comment: @marshalcraft I would ideally like to have both, the interpolation being continuous and being able to integrate that. But sadly in my numerics class we only ever talked about methods for interpolating a single variable and not two, so I have a limit idea into how to approach this problem.

Comment: This problem is making a lot more sense now. Interpolation is a way to derive the velocity field of a fluid over a region (which can be a line segment); integration of some function of the velocity over a region could calculate a force. Once you have set up the relevant models and formulas in principle (without worrying yet about things like the size of your $\Delta y$) you may be able to apply some simplifications, such as Simpson's rule to integrate over an interval using only the values at the observed step points.

Comment: @DavidK So would it almost be better for me to use something like Simpson's Rule to integrate the velocity field at each time step than to interpolate that for all time ? I.e at $t=0$ use Simpson's rule, store that value than at $t=0.5$ use Simpson's rule, store that value then interpolate for the values of $t$ ?

Comment: Maybe. What I'm suggesting is that you work out the mathematics of what you want to model as if you had perfect information and algorithms that always give exact answers, and then see what you can do with the imperfect information and approximate algorithms you actually can get. I wouldn't apply Simpson until you have figured out exactly what function you want to integrate and exactly what interval you want to integrate it over. Integrating the velocity field seems unlikely to be what you want--my guess is you should integrate the _effect_ of the velocity, whatever that effect is.

Comment: Ok so I've thought more. Abstractly it is after holding $x$ and $z$ constant; a map $\mathbf V(y,t): \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^4$. A surface in 4D space. One integral would give the 4D hypervolume underneath the the surface $\mathbf U$ bouned by the square/rectangular region where $y,t$ varies. But isn't for constant $x,z$. Sorry this part confuses me because it can't be the hypervolume because points inbetween the the two surfaces would have different $x,z$. So I think it would be an integral which computes the surface area. If so this can be done by connecting the points into a mesh made of n-gons

Comment: I'm not sure if it works the same as in three dimensions where three points define a plane, purhapse it is four now? But you should be able to form hyperplanes from the points, and the compute the area of the plane and sum them together to approximate the integral. It's derivatives would not be continuous but would be similar to just approximating a curve by strait lines, the more points the better.

Comment: Also I may confuse some terminology because I'm not sure if a 4D surface is a 3D volume? But the surface here is a 2D surface because it only has to parameters and I know a surface requires at least two parameters. But yeah the function $\mathbf V$ clearly is a surface in the $y,t$ direction. Thinking of integrals which make sense we have simple surface area, flux through it (weighted surface area).

Comment: After thinking about it some more, if we viewed $ \mathbf V$ projected from 4D to either the $x,y,z$ or $x,z,t$ 3D space it then would be a volume, or at least appear that way. In the other possible projections to 3D space it would be a surface, and I don't know in full 4D?

Comment: Also the metric or 4D distance would have to be defined. Maybe just 3D Cartesian distance ignoring the $t$ dimension.